# Compiler that supports c++11 for Windows vista

Tags: c++11, compiler-construction

I'm currently studying a book regarding C++, which is quite new. Therefore it also discusses C++11 in some parts. Having Windows Vista, I can't download the latest version of Visual Express, so I'll have to do with the 2010 version. This doesn't support C++11, so I'm currently wondering whether there exists a free alternative which does support C++11.

p.s. - Would you say it's essential/important for a beginner in programming to learn C++11 as well (instead of just the core basics)?

Comment: Try [MinGW](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/)

Comment: You seem to be looking for and IDE as well as a compiler.  Both CodeBlocks and Eclipse can be set up to use a compiler of your choice (go with GCC4.8/MinGW imho) and are free.

Comment: VS2010 supports many features of C++11, though by no means all of them. You might be able to get away with it at least partially.

Comment: I definitely wouldn't use VS2010 if you want to use C++11.

Comment: If you want to go for Visual Studio, try the 2012 (with CTP November) or 2013 preview. They support more C++11 features than 2010, though they're far from being feature-complete.

Comment: @tehinternetsismadeofcatz: He said he is on Windows Vista. VS2012 doesn't support Vista.

Comment: @Kyle_the_hacker Oh yeah you're right, sorry.

Comment: You're looking for MinGW

Answer (score 2):

You could consider using virtual machine with a Linux flavor. I had the same problem as you, I installed VirtualBox, then Ubuntu having the latest g++ compiler

Answer (score 0):

You could compile and use [Clang on Windows Vista and integrate it to Visual Studio](http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html#buildWindows). They have an [almost complete support for C++11](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html) now (as of version 3.3).